# Fixed Size SVG Background Image

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a shape I'm trying to put on top of a text box with a background image.  This shape will go in different sized containers and scale responsively.  The issue I'm having is the background image scales as well, and I would like for it to stay the same size without using a clip path.  Please see the code for what I'm talking about.  This is driving me crazy!

```css
.container {
  width: 75%;
}

.box {
  background-image: url("https://s22.postimg.org/dhkk3e8sh/Blue_881.jpg");
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

p {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<svg width="100%" height="auto"  viewBox="375 265 1268 45.3">
  
  <defs>
 <pattern id="img1" height="30%" width="30%"
         patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" 
         viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
    <image height="1" width="1"  preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" 
           xlink:href="https://s22.postimg.org/dhkk3e8sh/Blue_881.jpg" />
</pattern>
</defs>
  
  <path d="M369,291.8v19.7h1280v-22.7c0,0-137-21.6-277-21.6c-308,0-534,34.9-726,34.9C460,302.2,369,291.8,369,291.8z" fill="url(#img1)" />
</svg>

<div class="box">
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nec tamen ille erat sapiens quis enim hoc aut quando aut ubi aut unde 
  </p>
  
  </div>
```

If you change the percentage size of the container, you'll see what I'm talking about.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you want. Do you mean if you halve the width, you only want to see half of the "wave"?

Comment: Right, I'm looking for the background of the SVG to stay a fixed size like the background on the text box, and not scale when the browser resizes.

If you go Full Page with the example, you'll see the background scales a lot larger on the svg than the text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a start you will need to get rid of the `viewBox` in the SVG. That causes the SVG to get scaled, and that affects anything in the SVG.  You'll also want the pattern to be 1:1, so that means switching to `patternContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` and have the pattern use the image at actual size.

We are also using `overflow:hidden` so that the non-scaling SVG will not force the parent SVG to be wider.

This gets you close. The pattern is now 1:1 but it doesn't exactly line up with the HTML one because they have differing pattern origins.  You can adjust that by tweaking the `x` and `y` attributes of the pattern until it lines up correctly.  I'll leave that to you.

```css
.container {
  width: 75%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  background-image: url("https://s22.postimg.org/dhkk3e8sh/Blue_881.jpg");
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

p {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<svg width="1268" height="45.3">
  <defs>
 <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="881" height="192">
    <image width="881" height="192" 
           xlink:href="https://s22.postimg.org/dhkk3e8sh/Blue_881.jpg" />
</pattern>
</defs>
  
  <path transform="translate(-375 -265)"
        d="M369,291.8v19.7h1280v-22.7c0,0-137-21.6-277-21.6c-308,0-534,34.9-726,34.9C460,302.2,369,291.8,369,291.8z" fill="url(#img1)" />
</svg>

<div class="box">
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nec tamen ille erat sapiens quis enim hoc aut quando aut ubi aut unde 
  </p>
  
  </div>
```

Comment: Awesome!  This does just about what I need it to do.
Is it impossible to scale the whole SVG without clipping any off?

Thank you for looking into this for me.  I really appreciate the help.

Comment: If you scale the SVG, you scale its contents. The only way around that would be to scale the pattern up or down to compensate. You would need to attach an event to the onresize event, calculate the inverse transform, and apply it to the pattern.. I'm not sure how well that would work in practice though.